# gem exconタイムアウト値の設定について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

RonRのwebシステムでgem exconを使用しています。[excon](https://github.com/excon/excon/blob/v0.16.4/lib/excon.rb)

webシステムで処理に時間が掛かりすぎる為、タイムアウトして以下のようなエラーになります。

```
read timeout reached
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@production/gems/excon-0.16.4/lib/excon/socket.rb:107:in `rescue in read'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@production/gems/excon-0.16.4/lib/excon/socket.rb:83:in `read'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@production/gems/excon-0.16.4/lib/excon/response.rb:21:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@production/gems/excon-0.16.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:273:in `request_kernel'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@production/gems/excon-0.16.4/lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in `request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@production/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:20:in `request'
```

処理に時間が掛かるのは業務上仕方なくデフォルトタイムアウト値を伸ばすことを考えています。

```
connection.request(:read_timeout => 360)
```

呼び出し元を上記のようにすればタイムアウト値を伸ばすことができるのは分かったのですが
他のタイムアウト値（write_timeout、connect_timeout）も伸ばすべきなのか何に使われているか分かりません。どなたかご存知の方は教えて頂きたく

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read_timeout値を伸ばすと動作するようになりました。